# TextArea field Validation in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Can any one suggest text areas field validation in asp.net mvc.I tried many ways but  no luck

My View for text area:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.EmailTemplate, new { rows = "10", cols = "150", @class = "form-control", @id = "Email", required = "required", @maxlength = "10000" }) 
@Html.ValidationMessagefor(m => m.EmailTemplate, new { @class = "text-danger"}); 
@Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

My Model:

```
[AllowHtml] 
[Required(ErrorMessage ="Email Template is required")] 
public string EmailTemplate { get; set; }
```

---

---

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@Html.ValidationMessagefor(m => m.EmailTemplate, new { @class = "text-danger"});
```

To

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailTemplate, null, new { @class = "text-danger"})
```

As the second parameter of `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` takes optional validation message (use null or ""), and the third parameter takes the htmlAttributes `@class` etc.

Answer (score 0):

For TextAreaFor Validation in Model, I have applied **"[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]"** attribute to make it work.

**Model**

```
public class DemoModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]

    public string EmailTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model WebRedis.Models.DemoModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailTemplate)
                <br />
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.EmailTemplate, new { rows = "10", cols = "150", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "10000" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailTemplate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image]